# Why aren't the outlines of the preview device not shown in Android Studio 2.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Please help me out.
I tried updating the plugins and other things like rebilding the code,etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it always looks like when using ScrollView as root element.

If you use RelativeLayout for example, you'll see that it'll work as expected.

Comment: Thank you sir for your help.I am grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Choose include device frame(if available) option from preview pane

[image: Setting -> Include device frames]